# Getting CEST time from the Microsoft Windows Time Zone Database

Tags: c#, timezone, timezone-offset

There are a lot of countries which change from `CET` *(Central European Time)* to `CEST` *(Central European Summer Time)* during `DST` *(Daylight Saving Time)*.

So I thought that the Microsoft timezone database would have `CEST` as a time zone but I can only find `CET`.

> CET has an UTC-Offset of +1
>
> CEST has an UTC-Offset of +2

Would it be a problem if I would simply use another timezone with the same offset as `CEST`? And if so, how else am I supposed to get the `CEST` time from the database?

Comment: There is only one timezone setting.  Not two (summer/winter).  You use just the standard time and software know when the transition occurs.  Same exists in US where Daylight savings time has been used for a long time.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms912391(v=winembedded.11)

Comment: @jdweng the problem is that there are some countries which don't change to CEST and I think even some which change to CEST on a different date than the other countries. So how does the software know when to transition if it isn't the same for all countries using CET?

Comment: You can only use CET if all countries comply with the standard including summer/winter.  So you have to use the timezone for the country if CEST is not supported.

Comment: Look at the link I provided,  There are two very similar timezones.  One has an "an' at the end and the other doesn't. 095 Central Europe Standard Time (GMT+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague
100 Central European Standard Time (GMT+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the help! The timezone I have to use is: 110 W. Europe Standard Time

Comment: @jdweng - That list is really old.  Please don't link to it.  It does not represent the modern Windows experience.  Instead, use `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` in .Net, or `tzutil /L` on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft Windows time zones that include the word "Standard" in their identifiers, such as `Pacific Standard Time`, `Central Europe Standard Time` or  `W. Europe Standard Time` still represent the entirety of the time zone - including periods that might be under daylight saving time (aka "summer time").

**You should not choose a different time zone during the DST period.**

There is only one caveat: Windows computers have a date/time setting called "Adjust for daylight saving time automatically".  This is on by default, and in most cases should never be turned off.  However, if a user *has* turned it off, then they will not get the benefit of the system understanding how to apply daylight time correctly.

In .NET (as you tagged your question C#), this behavior only surfaces on Windows through APIs that use the system-local time zone, such as `DateTime.Now` or `TimeZoneInfo.Local`.  If you ask for a time zone by its identifier, DST is always applied correctly regardless of the system's DST setting.